# How to copy paste contents in the vi editor

Tags: editor, vi

I tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for pasting contents in a vi editor document, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> is not interpreted as a paste.

Comment: Just a note, the main reason to use Vi is because Vim isn't installed. If you have Vim installed, it's probably worth using that instead. There isn't really an advantage to Vi besides that it is already present on every Unix install. The best way to learn Vim in my opinion is to open your terminal emulator (not from within Vim) and type `vimtutor` It will get you up to speed to where it's usable to you in about 45 minutes.

Comment: +1 @BenMordecai - I was already familiar with vi (from old), including its convenient sub-shell capability, but needed that refresh. Great little bit of tutoring. Went through it like a breeze. Thanks.

Comment: Checkout my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666057/9384511

Answer (score 273, accepted):

First, make sure you're in edit mode (press <kbd>i</kbd>). Then you can paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, if you're in a terminal emulator like `gnome-terminal` (or select "Paste" from the right-click menu).

You can also type `:set paste` in vim before you paste to disable automated indenting, etc. Then `:set nopaste` after you've pasted the content.

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2555559/252239) on stackoverflow.com for more information.

If you want to copy/paste lines in `vim` (as opposed to pasting clipboard content), you'll want to check out the **yank** command. Here is a [cheat sheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20161221161539/http://bullium.com/support/vim.html#move) that might help.

Comment: I think if you have mouse cursor on, you cannot paste using Ctrl+Shift+V.

Comment: Just a note, the `I` is case-sensitive. The lowercase `i` is the normal way of entering insert mode. Capital `I` brings the cursor to the beginning of the line and then enters you into insert mode.

Comment: the `:set paste` is a lifesaver!

Answer (score 77):

Vi (and Vim) works very differently compared to a normal text editor such as Gedit. It also has a pretty steep learning curve. If you want to learn some basic commands, start with [this interactive tutorial](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html).

However, to answer you question. The system clipboard's content can be accessed through the plus register. So to paste something from the system clipboard you can, from the Normal mode, press: <kbd>"+p</kbd> (Not at the same time, but one after another).

Comment: This is something I did not know till now. Also, +1 for linking yet another awesome vim tutorial.

Comment: Speaking of learning curves for editors, there is the "classical learning curves for some common editors", http://blog.thilelli.net/public/store/attached/curves.jpg.

Comment: In GNOME Terminal, the short-cuts for copy and paste are Ctrl-Shift-C and Ctrl-Shift-V, respectively.

Comment: I've tried to press in turn <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>, also <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> and nothing has happened. What I've done wrong? I use `vi` not `vim`

Comment: I just wanted to add that `"+p` does not always work in Ubuntu.

Comment: That's the right answer. Using eg. Ctrl-Shift-v will work only with the simplest contents (line breaks and indentations can get really wrong if you're in the terminal, and you forgot to use `set :paste`).

Comment: The right answer IMO is to past with SHIFT + P in command mode.

Comment: -1, not an answer for the question itself.

Answer (score 41):

I always use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> when I want to paste text into the terminal, works in all terminal programs.

(Which is also the reason why I never get a laptop where you can't press <kbd>Insert</kbd> without pressing a secondary key)

Comment: `Vi`/`Vim` != terminal ;)

Comment: +1 for this.. What do you use to perform say `Ctrl+A`,`Ctrl+C` also ?

Comment: If I use a terminal inside a DE I usually just select text with the mouse and copy with Ctrl+Shift+C.

Comment: Shift+Insert also works in gvim. (I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, if that makes any difference.)

Comment: best solution. First open the File. Then press I for insert-Mode, then press Shift + Insert, then Esc, then :wq! to save and exit file. Done :)

Comment: Thank you for this! In my case using CTRL+SHIFT+V was not an option because it's used and automatically catched by a clipboard-history tool I'm using. But SHIFT+INSERT worked perfectly.

Answer (score 32):

1. If you want to copy paste contents **within the same file**, use `yank` and `paste`.
2. If you want to copy paste contents **across terminals**, open the first file, yanking the text you want, then open your second file within vim (e.g. `:tabnew /path/to/second/file`) and press `p` to paste it.
3. If you want to copy paste contents **from vim to an external program**, you need to access the system clipboard. I assume you use Ubuntu. The GUI version of vim always has clipboard support, however, if you like to use Vim from a terminal, you will have to check for X11-clipboard support.

   From the console, type:

   ```
   $ vim --version | grep xterm
   ```

   If you find **-xterm_clipboard**, you have two options:

   1) Compile vim yourself, with the xterm_clipboard flag on

   2) Uninstall vim, install **gvim** (vim-gtk or vim-gnome) instead. You can stick to non-gui vim by calling vim from the terminal, the same way you did before. This time when you check you should find **+xterm_clipborad**.

   Now, when you yank some text in the + register inside your vim editor (e.g. "+yy), it also gets copied to the system clipboard which you can retrieve from your external program like gedit editor, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.
4. If you want to copy paste contents **from an external program into vim**, first copy your text into system clipboard via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, then in vim editor **insert mode**, click the **mouse middle button** (usually the wheel) or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

   These are 4 basic **copy & paste** conditions related to vim. I hope this helps.

Comment: What's the point of :tabnew /path/to/second/file ? You can achieve the exact same thing yanking/copying/cutting in first file, opening the second file with :vi  /path/to/second/file and pasting (p/P) in it. At least in my case... Or is it because I do have the +xterm_clipboard vim feature enabled ? Or is there more to tabnew than just that ?

Comment: On Ubuntu `vim-gtk` has `xterm_clipboard` support and on Fedora `xvim` has it.

Answer (score 10):

Use the *center button of the mouse* to insert text you've highlighted elsewhere.

It is useful when you don't have access to your system clipboard (for example, in a remote SSH session).

Must be in edit/insert mode for Vim.

Comment: What if you are using a laptop with only touchpad at your disposal? Then your solution won't work.

Answer (score 9):

Once you enter vi, press `i` to get into insert mode, right click into terminal, click paste.

Comment: I thought was lower-case `i`. What does upper-case `I` do?

Comment: @Flimm that was already explained in a comment by Ben Mordecai on another answer.

Comment: I've edited the answer to be lower-case `i`. Upper-case `I` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line before entering insert mode, which is not needed here.

Answer (score 8):

Detailed instructions to copy/paste lines of text in vi using `yank` and `put`

(use the following in the **command mode** of vi)

**Copy (YANK)**

To copy one line in vi:

- In the command mode, move the cursor to the line that needs to be copied and type `yy` or type `Y`

To copy 2 lines in vi:

- In the command mode, move the cursor to the first line that needs to be copied and type `2yy` or type `2Y`

(likewise, any number of lines can be copied)

To copy all lines from the current location to the end of the file:

- In the command mode, move the cursor to the first line that needs to be copied and type `yG`

To copy all text from the current location to the end of the current word:

- In the command mode, move the cursor to location from where text needs to be copied and type `yw`

To copy all text from the current location to the end of the line:

- In the command mode, move the cursor to location from where text needs to be copied and type `y$`

**Paste (PUT)**

To paste text in the clipboard - **after** the location of the cursor:

- In the command mode, type `p`

To paste text in the clipboard - **before** the location of the cursor:

- In the command mode, type `P`

Answer (score 6):

With Vim 8+ on Linux or Mac, you can now simply use the OS' native paste (`ctrl+shift+V` on Linux, `cmd+V` on Mac). Do not press `i` for Insert Mode.

It will paste the contents of your OS clipboard, preserving the spaces and tabs without adding autoindenting. It's equivalent to the old `:set paste`, `i`, `ctrl+shift+V`, `esc`, `:set nopaste` method.

You don't even need the `+clipboard` or `+xterm_clipboard` vim features installed anymore. This feature is called "bracketed paste". For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514445/turning-off-auto-indent-when-pasting-text-into-vim/56781763#56781763

Comment: That's the answer I'm looking for. Since Vim is not default on gnu/linux distros, it needs to be installed even in ubuntu. Additionally, Vi's up down buttons doesn't work on ubuntu and no highlight.

Comment: why isn't this voted  significantly higher?!

Comment: works in 'vi' too, easiest answer by far.

Comment: For mac users, this is the answer cmd+V , as mentioned in this comment.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue, because my Vim installation was not supporting **the clipboard**:

```
vim --version | grep clip
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
```

I installed vim-gnome (which supports the clipboard) and then checked again:

```
vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
```

Now I am able to copy and paste using "+y and "+p respectively.

Comment: This fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2):

First, check if your vim has clipboard support installed

```
:echo has('clipboard')
```

If it returns 1 you do have clipboard support

To copy to the clipboard you have to either select your target, let's say a paragraph `vip` and then `"+y`, which means to the register `+` copy the selected portion or you can simply type in normal mode: `"+yip`, which means: to the register `+` copy inner paragraph.

To paste from the clipboard in normal mode you can:

```
"+p
```

On insert mode you can simply <kbd>Ctrl-r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>. Tha will insert your clipboard content and preserve all indentation as it is on the clipboard.

If you want to copy the whole buffer to the clipboard you can:

```
:%y+
% ........ the whole file
y ........ yank (copy)
+ ........ to the clipboard
```

To copy the last command to the clipboard:

```
:let @+=@:
```

To copy the last search to the clipboard:

```
 :let @+=@/
```

to copy from the mark "a" until the mark "b" to the clipboard:

```
 :'a,'b y+
```

To test any function that is on the clipboard you can

```
:@+    (and then type Enter)
:call FunctionName() (and then type Enter)
```

To see what is on the clipboard:

```
:reg +
```

To copy all lines that have "pattern" to the clipboard you can:

```
:let @a=""
:[range]g/pattern/y A
:let @+=@a

:let @a="" ............ cleanses the register 'a'
:[range]g/pattern/y A   append to the register A every line with pattern
:let @+=@a ............ copy register 'a' to the clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in terminal version vim, But for GUI version vim like `Neovim-Qt`, pasting text from the system clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> simply won't work. You have to access to the clipboard `"+` or `"*` in the vim editor.

Adding new keybinding in `.vimrc` will simply the copy/paste commands:

```
" paste from system clipboard, align indentation with surroundings
noremap <Leader>p "*]p:set nopaste<CR>
" copy a sentence into system clipboard
noremap <Leader>y "+y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're **root**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

If you're **not-root**: Center click the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to note that using Vim via Git Bash on Windows, you can just use `p` or center-click of the mouse without being in insert mode. Using Vim through [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), you can just right click. And highlighting does the copying.

I've noted this because I got here not seeing that this is SE for Ubuntu.

**Other helpful commands:**

- <kbd>yy</kbd>(# of lines) - yank (copy)
- <kbd>dd</kbd>(# of lines) - delete
- <kbd>p</kbd> - paste line below current line
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> - paste line above current line
- <kbd>u</kbd> - undo
- <kbd>r</kbd> - redo
- <kbd>i</kbd> - insert mode
- <kbd>v</kbd> - visual mode

Comment: That did not work for me on Windows Git Bash. Which console are you using, mintty or windows cmd?

Comment: I believe it was mintty.