# clipboard problem in terminal text editors

Tags: vim, clipboard, nano

I am on Ubuntu 22.10, when I copy text from anywhere, there is no problem with pasting it on a regular other app. But I get errors when I try to paste the text into terminal text editors.

For example in **Nano** I get the error
`[ Cutbuffer is empty ]`

and in **VIM** :
`error E353: Nothing in register *`

I've tried this for vim in `.vimrc` :

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

and didn't work!

**NOTE:** when first open vim, running the above command in vim command bar causes the error to not be displayed, but the clipboard is empty and nothing pasted!

Comment: those editors use their own clipboards, not the system ones. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/256782/how-to-copy-paste-contents-in-the-vi-editor

Comment: You should update Ubuntu to a supported version (22.04 or later).

Comment: Thanks @esther i got it.

Comment: @autur i have wrong mentioned,  i am on 22.10 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [@esther](https://askubuntu.com/users/1083397/esther)'s guide, those editors **use their own clipboards**, not the system ones.
More details on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256782/how-to-copy-paste-contents-in-the-vi-editor)